# Place conference members on hold as they join, then un-hold ALL?

Tags: twilio

I'm building a Conference Call console app, where my client wants a Start Call button (instead of starting automatically when the moderator enters.) Since there's no API method for starting a conference, I'm thinking the conference will "start" when the first member enters, but then they'll immediately be put on hold. Later, the moderator will press the "Start Conference" button which will un-hold all the participants. I have 2 questions:

1. Can I add a .then to the dial.conference() that puts that call on hold, or some other way of doing it from that same runtime function? Or do I have to make an api call from my app when I get the callbackstatus that the member has joined?
2. When I have 175 participants waiting on hold, do I have to send the list of all their CallSids, or is there some way to un-hold all of them?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. Let's say the Conference is called Capistrano. I put all the participants into Capistrano with startConferenceOnEnter = false. They're happy.

Then, when a moderator calls in, I recognize them by their phone numbers and I put them into a different conference, Capistrano-backstage. They can chat with each other, etc.

Then, when they press the Start Call button, I make an API call that `<Dial>` them from Capisrano-backstage to Capistrano, with startConferenceOnEnter = true.

Effectively, the conference started when they pushed the button, but really, it started because they entered. Thanks to @philnash for the assist on the code:

```
// start-conference receives the Confname, Language and the CallSids of all facilitators 'backstage'
// then moves them all to the conference, which starts it.
// This is your new function. To start, set the name and path on the left.

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  switch (event.Language) {
      case 'es-MX':  
        connectnow = 'Ahora lo estare conectando con '+ event.Confname ;
        break;
      default :
        connectnow = 'Now starting ' + event.Confname;
        break;
    }
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();
  
    const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  twiml.say(connectnow, {voice: 'Polly.Kendra', language: event.Language});
  const dial = twiml.dial();
  // conf-backstage settings for facilitators
  dial.conference({
      statusCallback: context.STATUSCALLBACKURL,
      statusCallbackEvent: 'start join speaking mute leave',
      startConferenceOnEnter: true,
      endConferenceOnExit: false,
      muted: false,
    },
    event.Confname);
    
  function transfer(CallSid) {
    return client.calls(CallSid).update({ twiml: twiml });
  }

  Promise.all(event.callSid.map(transfer))
    .then(() => {
      return callback(null, "success");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return callback(error);
    });    
};
```

Comment: Glad you solved it, interesting approach with the `backstage` and otherwise pretty much what I suggested ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can I add a .then to the dial.conference() that puts that call on hold, or some other way of doing it from that same runtime function? Or do I have to make an api call from my app when I get the callbackstatus that the member has joined?

You dial them into the conference via a `<Dial>` and `<Conference>` TwiML, see [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference). You would set the `startConferenceOnEnter` attribute to `false` for all of the participants, see [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-startConferenceOnEnter), that puts them "on hold".

> 2. When I have 175 participants waiting on hold, do I have to send the list of all their CallSids, or is there some way to un-hold all of them?

You have two options: **A)** You can have the moderator dial in and set the `startConferenceOnEnter` attribute to `true` for them, this would start the conference. **B)** If you want a button somewhere in your UI you would need to use the Twilio Rest API, specifically the [Conference Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-resource). The status should be in `init` and you should set it to `in-progress`. But I'm not sure about that, an alternative would be to get the moderator via the [Conference Participant Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource) and then set the `startConferenceOnEnter` attribute to `true`. You need to experiment a bit.